# Adjusting Width for an Absolute DIV block

Tags: html, css, width

I will try to explain my situation the best that I can.

I have a site where it displays a list of DIV blocks with info inside. 3 DIV blocks are created using width:33%

Inside that div block I want another hidden div block that is exactly the same as the previous div block.

So I have something like this....

```
<div class="columnParent">
      <div class="columnChild">
            "Various stuff here that overlaps parent DIV"
      </div>

      "Various text that initially appears, but disappears after clicking a button"
</div>
```

Here is the CSS...

```
.columnParent { width:31%; float: left; margin-right:15px; margin-bottom:4%; }
.columnChild { width:31%; float: left; margin-right:15px; margin-bottom:4%; visibility:hidden; position: absolute;
background: #FFF;}
```

Now what happens when the child DIV is visible, it ends up being larger than the parent. This is because the width:31% is taking 31% of the entire HTML page, while the parent div is taking 31% of its parent div(not listed here).

Is there a way to get the child DIV to take the same width as its parent?

I want the Child div to be an exact replica of its parent div. I will be changing the text inside, but the actual div should be the same size and be in the exact same position.

---

Purpose: I have a button that displays the child div to make the parent disappear and display a new child div that has different information. Inside the child div there will be a back button to make that div disappear again (using JS).

Any help is greatly appreciated!!! Thanks!

Comment: I might just use my already implemented JavaScript to add a display:none; to the parent div elements and hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0):

put the child element `width: 100%;` , then it will take the exact width of parent element. After that,  you can include jQuery to fadeIn/fadeOut the child element and manipulate it as you wish in javascript codes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by giving width 100% and position relative to columnChild, like below.

```
.columnChild { 
    width:100%; 
    float: left; 
    margin-right: 15px; 
    margin-bottom: 4%; 
    visibility: hidden; 
    position: relative;
    background: #FFF;
}
```

Note: Position relative will help to adjust the position relative to the parent position and width 100% will help to make the same width as the parent div.

Comment: Thanks for that! I tried what you said, and it ended up putting my Child block on top of the parent block. It did indeed make the width the correct length though, so thank you for that! Now I am one step closer